# store data's from web service in android so that the asynctask loads only first time the application launch

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

how to store data’s from web service in android so that the Async task loads only first time the application launch.
I know that using shared preference to check whether it is first launch or not.but I don't know how(or where) to store the data from web service and reuse it by setting those values to respective views.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you that how you want to store the data. In my case, I used to save the received json in sharedprefernce. on app launch I used to check if shared preference is null for that key then fetch the data otherwise just parse the saved Json and use it.